# Fast search through custom base adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, custom-adapter, fastsearch

I have a list and want to perform fast search in that list through custom base adapter.

followed this link but this is not for base adapter.

[fast Search android](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/12/android-listview-sectionindexer-fastscroll.html)

As I cannot override set adapter method in my custom base adapter.

I just want like this one [image]:-